# How to distinguish read/write operations when using operator[]

Tags: c++

I'd need to write a class with an overloaded operator [] which has different behavior when the operator [] is used to read or write data.
To give a practical example of what I want to achieve, let's say I have to write the implementation of a class named PhoneBook which can be used in the following way:

```
PhoneBook phoneBook(999999); // 999999 is the default number which should be
                             // used when calling someone who is not in the phone book

phoneBook["Paul"] = 234657;  // adds Paul's number
phoneBook["John"] = 340156;  // adds John's number

// next line should print Paul's number 234657
cout << "To call Paul dial " << phoneBook["Paul"] << endl;
// next line should print John's number 340156
cout << "To call John dial " << phoneBook["John"] << endl;
// next line should print 999999 because Frank is not in the phone book
cout << "To call Frank dial " << phoneBook["Frank"] << endl;
```

The problem is in the fact that when using

```
phoneBook["Frank"]
```

I don't want to add an entry in the phone book for Frank, otherwise a solution based on std::map would be easy to implement.

I did not find on the web any standard way to achieve this so 
after some thinking I came up with the following solution in which the operator [] returns a "temporary object" named PhoneNumber. PhoneNumber is then used to distinguish between read/write operations:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class PhoneBook{
private:
    map<string, int> data_; // stores phone numbers
    int defaultNumber_; // default number returned when no matching name is found

public:
    PhoneBook(int defaultNumber) :
        defaultNumber_(defaultNumber) {}

    // Searches in the phone book for a name. If the name is found it returns
    // the corresponding number. If the name is not found it returns defaultNumber_
    int read(string name){
        map<string, int>::iterator it = data_.find(name);
        if (it==data_.end()){
            return defaultNumber_;
        } else {
            return it->second;
        }
    }

    // Forwarding function to map operator []. It is not really necessary but it is added for clarity
    int& write(string name){
        return data_[name];
    }

    // Forward declaration of the "temporary object" returned by operator []
    // See declaration below
    class PhoneNumber;

    PhoneNumber operator[](string name){
        return PhoneNumber(this, name);
    }

    class PhoneNumber{
        friend class PhoneBook;
    private:
        PhoneBook* const phoneBook_;
        string name_;

        // Constructors are private so that PhoneNumber can be used only by PhoneBook
        // Default constructor should not be used
        PhoneNumber() :
            phoneBook_(NULL) {}

        PhoneNumber(PhoneBook* phoneBook, string name) :
            phoneBook_(phoneBook), name_(name) {}

    public:
        // conversion to int for read operations
        operator int (){
            return phoneBook_->read(name_);
            }

        // assignment operator for write operations
        const int& operator = (const int& val){
            return phoneBook_->write(name_) = val;
        }
    };
};

int main(){
    PhoneBook phoneBook(999999);

    phoneBook["Paul"] = 234657;
    phoneBook["John"] = 340156;

    cout << "To call Paul dial " << phoneBook["Paul"] << endl;
    cout << "To call John dial " << phoneBook["John"] << endl;
    cout << "To call Frank dial " << phoneBook["Frank"] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The class PhoneBook behaves like I would like and the program prints:

```
To call Paul dial 234657
To call John dial 340156
To call Frank dial 999999
```

I would like to ask you some questions:

1. Is there any better way to obtain a class behaving like the class I coded?
2. Has the technique I'm using a name so that I can search more info about it?
3. Do you see any drawback/possible improvement in my solution?

In the library I'm writing, enabling the behavior I obtained for PhoneBook::operator[]
in a similar situation is really important and I would really like to know what you think about my problem.

Thanks!

Comment: +1. Sort of good question and attempted answer.

Comment: This is the C++ solution, I can't think of any better. Just to add some information, C# is a language that would allow you to change the behavior of the get and set operations of the operator[]. (http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/Lesson18.aspx).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you propose is the standard solution to this problem.  It's usually
known as the proxy pattern or proxy idiom, and the helper class that you
return is called a proxy.  (Since it is a nested class, simply calling
it `Proxy` is generally sufficient.)

Comment: I didn't realize what I'm using is a proxy. Maybe it is because I have never seen a proxy used this way...Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think you may implement two versions of operator [], one with const modifier and the other without. Then if you has a       object say `PhoneBook phoneBook(999999);`, the if phoneBook is const object, only `operator [] const` can be called. If       phoneBook is non-const object, default `operator []` is called. If you want to call `operator [] const` given a non-const     object, you may add a cast like `static_cast<const PhoneBook&>(phoneBook)->operator[...]`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class PhoneBook{
private:
    map<string, int> data_; // stores phone numbers
    int defaultNumber_; // default number returned when no matching name is found

public:
    PhoneBook(int defaultNumber) :
        defaultNumber_(defaultNumber) {}
    int operator [] (const string& name) const
    {
        map<string, int>::const_iterator it = data_.find(name);
        if (it == data_.end())
        {
            return defaultNumber_;
        }
        else
        {
            return it->second;
        }
    }
    int& operator [] (const string& name)
    {
        return data_[name];
    }
};

int main(){
    PhoneBook phoneBook(999999);

    phoneBook["Paul"] = 234657;
    phoneBook["John"] = 340156;

    cout << "To call Paul dial " << phoneBook["Paul"] << endl;
    cout << "To call John dial " << phoneBook["John"] << endl;
    cout << "To call Frank dial " << static_cast<const PhoneBook&>(phoneBook)["Frank"] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In general I prefer using static_cast only when necessary. Having two versions of operator[] would be the solution if the const version would be the one selected by default (in this case the compiler should understand automatically if you are writing or reading)

Comment: @carlo: Forgive I misunderstood your purpose in my post. I think what you actually want is: when reading a non-existing number, just return the default number without inserting. For your problem, I think your solution is good enough. We need either store a proxy object in the map or return a proxy object. However, the semantic change of `operator []` may confuse users of you lib. For instance, one may assume your class similar to a map and write `int& n = phoneBook["Paul"];`, which fails to be compiled.

Comment: @carlo: In addition, you may not call `operator []` if you have a const PhoneBook