# Determine lvalue and rvalue in C++ function

Tags: c++

UPDATE: I revised some place, and now the problem has changed in some way.

I'm writing a C++ class. Like:

```
class qqq{
    map<int,int> core;
    //......
    int& operator[](int n){return core[n];};
};
int main(){
    qqq a;
    a[3]=7;a[5]=0;//Case a
    int b=a[3];//Case b
    return 0;
}
```

Although case A and case B are calling the same function(overloaded operator), but case a is used as an lvalue while case b is used as a rvalue.

For some reason, I want to have the effect that if 0 is passed to a[5], delete the node 5 in core. Like:

```
int& operator[](int n){
    if(CASE A && THE VALUE PASSED TO IT IS 0)
        core.erase(core.find(n));
    else
        return core[n];
}
```

Maybe my description is not accurate.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330815/how-to-distinguish-read-write-operations-when-using-operator

Comment: You probably need a proxy class.

Comment: Quick and dirty idea: Declare a "garbage" field, which you can return in that case.

Comment: You will have to return _something_ if you function is declared `int&`.

Comment: actually I wouldn't do it... It seems that it would lead to quite an unreadable code (a[5] = 3; a{5]=0; -> would result in a[5] being 3...)

Comment: Changing the question is not ok. Create a new question instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation of the proxy pattern mentioned in the comments.

Personally, I don't use this, my maps are wrapped in classes that don't provide `operator[]` at all, instead there are functions like `.get(key, default)` `.init(key)`, `.setdefault(key, default)`, etc. depending on the class.

```
// This code is C++11 but it's not essential to the problem.
// The current code calls copy constructors more than necessary.
#include <map>

#include <cassert>


template<class K, class V>
struct zero_map
{
    struct proxy
    {
        std::map<K, V> *container;
        K key;

        operator V()
        {
            auto it = container->find(key);
            if (it == container->end())
                return V();
            return *it;
        }
        void operator = (V value)
        {
            if (value == V())
            {
                container->erase(key);
            }
            else
            {
                // probably should use .insert() and conditionally assign
                (*container)[key] = value;
            }
        }
    };

    std::map<K, V> _inner;

    proxy operator[](K k)
    {
        return proxy{&_inner, k};
    }
};

int main()
{
    zero_map<int, int> foo;
    assert (foo._inner.size() == 0);
    foo[1] = 0;
    assert (foo._inner.size() == 0);
    foo[0] = 1;
    assert (foo._inner.size() == 1);
    foo[0] = 0;
    assert (foo._inner.size() == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a comment said, use a proxy class.

```
template<typename T, size_t BadIndex>
class Element{ // please use a more meaningful name
    public:
        Element(const size_t index): index(index){}

        operator T& (){return value;}
        operator T const&() const{return value;}

        T &operator =(const T &rhs){
            if(index != BadIndex)
                value = rhs;
            return value;
        }

        operator T const&() const{return value;}
        operator T&(){return value;}

    private:
        T value;
        const size_t index;
};

class qqq{
    public:
        std::map<int, Element<int, 5>> core;

        Element<int> &operator [](size_t index){
            auto itt = core.find(index);
            if(itt == core.end()){
                core.emplace(index, index);
                itt = core.find(index);
            }
            return (*itt).second;
        }
};
```

That should work, but 5 will always give you a garbage result.

Comment: aaaaaaand you changed it before I submitted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to always return a value which can be used as left value in the assignment expression. Therefore, I suggest to use a garbage `int` variable. I declared the `garbage` as static because we need just one instance of this variable and we don't care its value.

For example,

```
 class qqq{
    static int garbage;
    map<int,int> core;
    //......

    int& operator[](int n){
        if(CASE A && THE VALUE PASSED TO IT IS 0)
            return garbage;
        else
            return core[n];
    }
};
```

However, this solution is confusing in my point of view because the behaviour completely changes according to what you specify in the square brackets. If the value passed in input is incorrect, I would probably thrown an exception.

*** EDIT ***

I think you are over complicating the problem using the `[]` operator. You can easily solve your problem by using setter and getters. For example :

```
int set(int index, int value){
    if( value == 0)
        core.erase(core.find(index));
    else
        return core[index];
}

int get(int index) {
 return core[index];
}
```

The `[]` allows only for returning a reference, you don't know what is the value used in the assignment.

Comment: You haven't caught what I want to tell. n is not the value I want to pass to core[n] when used as a left value.

Comment: Nice idea, bad still defects in implementation. `garbage` could be static in `operator[]` to avoid pollution of global variables. And if you initialized `garbage` to `core[n]` and returned it when `n` is 0, it should to the trick ...

Comment: yes... I didn't want to put in the global scope. I just wrote quickly the code.

Comment: @袁轶君 what do you mean? `n` is the value passed in the brackets.

Comment: If a[123]=0, then I want to delete the node core[123] in a. if a[123]=5, then I want to set core[123] of a to the value of 5.

Comment: I roolbacked my edit because it was answering the wrong question.

Comment: @袁轶君 Thank you. I finally understood your problem and update my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You question is now clear, unfortunately you will have no way to do that is C++. `operator[]` is not a getter and a setter : it can only return a reference, and that reference is than used for a mere assignement. At the moment the operator returns its reference, you cannot know what value will be used for a assignement, and you can hardly know how the ref will be used.

IMHO what you need is more :

```
int getCore(int i) {
    return core[i];
}

void setCore(int i, int newval) {
    if (newval == 0) {
        core.erase(core.find(i));
    }
    else {
        core[i] == newval;
}
```

Comment: Yes... Thanks you any way. May be I should use two functions instead of using the [].